# Why function returns JSX.Element is not assignable to variable type Component in SolidJS?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webpack, eslint, solid-js

My IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) marking my App component [as not assignable to variable type Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqCfs.png), but it doesn't :(

I think the problem may be in my configs (I just used information from the official sites, I'm not very good at this).

But I noticed the following:

- if I import the JSX, then the [error disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWdbJ.png) (ofc "no-unused-vars" error appears).
- if I ignore these errors, the application [builds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLUiY.png) and [runs without any errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbNKd.png).
- in [ryansolid's repository with webpack + ts example](https://github.com/ryansolid/solid-ts-webpack) my IDE [shows the exact same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFqQf.png)

### UDP

I want to note that the code in `index.tsx` and `App.tsx` worked in [default Vite templates](https://github.com/solidjs/templates) and i'm pretty sure that this code is not the problem.

### UDP 2

[snnsnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7134134/snnsnn) pointed out a stupid mistake (`Index.tsx` changed) in the render method, but a new problem `Argument type () => JSX.Element is not assignable to parameter type () => JSX.Element` is a something more strange

App.tsx

```
import { Component, createSignal } from "solid-js";

const App: Component = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = createSignal<number>(0);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello Stack Overflow {count()} times</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount(count() + 1);
        }}
      >
        Say hello again
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

index.tsx

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import App from "./App";

render(() => <App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:solid/typescript"
  ],
  "overrides": [
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "solid"
  ],
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "webpack.config.js"
  ],
  "rules": {
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "solid",
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "solid-webpack-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "solid-js": "^1.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.21.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.1",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "babel-preset-solid": "^1.7.3",
    "eslint": "^8.39.0",
    "eslint-plugin-solid": "~0.12.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "webpack": "^5.80.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.3"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "jsxImportSource": "solid-js"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const config = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    devMiddleware: {
      publicPath: "/",
    },
    port: 3000,
  },
  mode: "development",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".json"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `render` function expects you to pass JSX element, not a component, so you need to either remove `:Component` type and let typesript derive the type or replace it with`App: () => JSXElement`.

```js
import { render } from 'solid-js/web';
import { JSXElement } from 'solid-js';

const App: () => JSXElement = () => {
  return <div>Hello World</div>;
};

render(() => <App />, document.querySelector('root')!);
```

The alternate form is also OK:

```js
render(App, document.querySelector('root')!);
```

https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest#render

Also Component type is not same as returning a JSX element, because the latter does not accept any parameters.
`Component` is not same as `() => JSXElement`.

Comment: I removed the `: Component` and that solved problem in App.tsx, but the render function still shows an error (this time completely irrational) `Argument type () => JSX.Element is not assignable to parameter type () => JSX.Element`
I used `: Component` because its definition is `export type Component<P = {}> = (props: P) => JSX.Element;` and it should be correct.

Comment: Oh, of course this is a mistake caused by a manic desire to try everything possible, but
`Argument type () => JSX.Element is not assignable to parameter type () => JSX.Element` makes me lose my mind

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue Ive used `Element` as type but needed `JSXElement`